# specify fixed effect two-level variable rma.mv

Tags: r, fixed, metafor

I am conducting a meta-analysis using rma.mv in the metafor package in R. I have the effect sizes (`yi`), the variance (`vi`), one moderator and two random-effect variables. 
Recently it was pointed out that I should include the variable `Method of detection` (two levels) into the model as a fixed-effect variable. 
So that is the problem. I am not sure how to specify this variable as fixed.

This is my code:

```
overall <- rma.mv(yi, vi, data = ef.s, 
                  method="REML",
                  mods = ~  PeriSam,
                  random = list(~1|species,
                                ~1|study),
                  R=list(species=vcv1))
```

In the help section of the function there is a bit explaining how to approach this but i think my lack of stats training keeps me from making it work. Also it seems to vary when you have moderatos as is my case.

Answer (score 0):

You just add it to the variables specified via `mods`. So, assuming that variable is called `MethodOfDetection`, then it would be `mods = ~ PeriSam + MethodOfDetection`.

Comment: Many thanks Wolfgang for your help. It turned out to be simplier than I expected!
Now, if I am not mistaken, to see the effect of `PeriSam` (I am only interested in this variable) and accounting for `MethodOfDetection`, I should add a `btt` vector and choose this variable `btt = 1`